# unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting ';' in /hermes/walnaweb05a/b2439//admin/dashboard.php on line 1215

Tags: php

Code is:

```
var pieOptions = {
      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke: true,
      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps: 100,
      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate: true,
      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale: false,
     ///Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
      responsive: true,
      // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
    };
```

Comment: your title explain all ... :)

Comment: That's json, not php?

Comment: Aha! It's probably short_open_tags, <%= is a valid PHP opening tag.

Comment: Actually, it annoyed me that I said it was json, it's just javascript object  :P

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your question content isn't the best. It's because of short_open_tags being on.

`<%` and `<%=` are both valid php tags, similar to `<?php` and `<?`.

Context:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: FWIW - Alternative PHP tags have been removed in PHP7.